# Autocompletar campo con jQuery, Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, autocompletar

Saludos, tengo un DAO.php donde declaro las funciones que realizan las peticiones a la BD, esta funcinción en concreto:

```
function select_all_unis(){
        $tecla_pulsada = $_POST['service'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM dumies WHERE studies LIKE '".$tecla_pulsada."%'";

        $conexion = connect::con();
        $res = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
        connect::close($conexion);
        return $res;
    }
```

Y luego en un controlador (controller.php) con diferentes 'case', en concreto el que uso es:

```
case 'list_studies':
        try{
            $daolawyer = new DAOShop();
            $rdo = $daolawyer->select_all_unis();
        }catch (Exception $e){
            echo json_encode("error");
            exit;
        }
        if(!$rdo){
            echo json_encode("error");
            exit;
        }else{
            while($lawyer = mysql_fetch_array($rdo)){
                echo '<div>
                        <a class="suggest-element" data="'.$lawyer['studies'].'" id="service'.$lawyer['dni'].'">'.utf8_encode($lawyer['studies']).'</a>
                    </div>';                   
            }
            exit;
        }
        break;
```

Que es llamado en un js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
//Al escribr dentro del input con id="service"
$('#service').keypress(function(){
    //Obtenemos el value del input
    var service = $(this).val();        
    var dataString = 'service='+service;

    //Le pasamos el valor del input al ajax
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "module/shop/controller/controller_shop.php?op=list_studies",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            //Escribimos las sugerencias que nos manda la consulta
            $('#suggestions').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
            //Al hacer click en algua de las sugerencias
            $('.suggest-element').on('click', function(){
                //Obtenemos la id unica de la sugerencia pulsada
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                //Editamos el valor del input con data de la sugerencia pulsada
                $('#service').val($('#'+id).attr('data'));
                //Hacemos desaparecer el resto de sugerencias
                $('#suggestions').fadeOut(1000);
            });              
        }
    });
});
```

});

Y este es el código del html.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" size="50" id="service" name="service" />
        <div id="suggestions"></div>
</form>
```

Solo me falta saber como dependiendo de las teclas que pulse la BD me devuelva unos valores o otros, por ejemplo el la BD tengo una serie de usuarios, con las universidades donde han estudiado, y quiero que al pulsar la tecla c la BD me devuelva las universidades que empiecen por c. Tengo entendido que sería algo com $_POST['services]; pero nose donde ponerlo exactamente, el código del que me he basado es: https://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/autocompletar-campo-con-jquery-ajax-y-php/ 
Pero claro mi estructura de Modelo, vista controlador es diferente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable `service` la estás enviando por AJAX al archivo module/shop/controller/controller_shop.php?op=list_studies mediante el atributo `data` de la función ajax():

```
$.ajax({
...
data: dataString,
...
})
```

La variable dataString contiene la tecla pulsada y la estás enviando por el método POST con el nombre de 'service':

```
var dataString = 'service='+service;
```

Por lo tanto ésta debe ser accesible en el archivo module/shop/controller/controller_shop.php?op=list_studies mediante `$_POST['service]`

Una vez que esta variable llegue por POST al archivo PHP que desees, lo único que tienes que hacer es formar una consulta SQL con las universidades que empiezen por dicha letra, algo así como:

```
$tecla_pulsada = $_POST['service'];
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM universidades WHERE nombe LIKE '".$tecla_pulsada."%'";
```

Comment: He editado el código más o menos como debería ser pero de esta forma no recibo, no se si el while, con el mysql_fetch_array están mal, tampoco se muy bien que hacen.

Comment: La variable `var dataString = 'service='+service;` cámbiala por `var dataString = {service: service};` y justo al inicio del archivo controller_shop.php haz un `var_dump($_POST['service']));`. Abre el inspector de chrome, ve a la pestaña network y busca el archivo controller_shop.php, haz click sobre él y mira que aparece en la pestaña Response. Te debe aparecer el var_dump() si todo a ido bien, o el error de PHP si ha ido mal.

Comment: Pfffff.... muchísimas gracias, era el js, gracias a tu código lo he corregido ahora ya me funciona perfectamente, gracias de verdad, pues no le he tirado horas intentando arreglarlo y era el dataString

Comment: Me alegro. Te doy un consejo, usa la consola de depuración del navegador, puedes hacer debug línea a línea con puntos de ruptura y ver mucho mejor todos esos fallos, sobre todo cuando usas AJAX.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, lo tendré en  cuenta.